# Python fails to compile a regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to detect all `set` from a cmake file using a python regex, fo the file below:

```
# Library to include
set(LIB_TO_INCLUDE 
        a
        b
        c)

# comon code (inclusion in source code)
set(SHARED_TO_INCLUDE d e f)

# Library to include
set(THIRD_PARTY g h)
```

I'd like to retrieve:

```
LIB_TO_INCLUDE a b c
SHARED_TO_INCLUDE d e f
THIRD_PARTY g h
```

I tested the regex `set\((?s:[^)])*?\)` (get all but `)` items following `set(`) using regex101.com (see https://regex101.com/r/aB5tX2/1), it apparently does what I want.

Now when I try to run `re.compile(r'set\((?s:[^)])*?\)')` from Python, I get the error:

```
  File "private\python_scripts\convert.py", line 34, in create_sde_files
    pattern = re.compile(r'set\((?s:[^)])*?\)')   File "b:\dev\vobs_ext_2015\tools_ext\python\Python34_light\lib\re.py", line 223, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)   File "b:\dev\vobs_ext_2015\tools_ext\python\Python34_light\lib\re.py", line 294, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)   File "b:\dev\vobs_ext_2015\tools_ext\python\Python34_light\lib\sre_compile.py", line 568, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)   File "b:\dev\vobs_ext_2015\tools_ext\python\Python34_light\lib\sre_parse.py", line 760, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)   File "b:\dev\vobs_ext_2015\tools_ext\python\Python34_light\lib\sre_parse.py", line 370, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))   File "b:\dev\vobs_ext_2015\tools_ext\python\Python34_light\lib\sre_parse.py", line 721, in _parse
    raise error("unknown extension") sre_constants.error: unknown extension
```

Is this kind of regex not supported by Python?

Comment: Python doesn't support `(?s:`, no. You can use `(?s)` or `re.S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it: `set\(([^)]*?)\)`

The "single line" modifier is passed as an argument when you compile the regex:

```
>>> t = """set(LIB_TO_INCLUDE 
...         a
...         b
...         c)"""
>>> 
>>> pattern = r'set\(([^)]*?)\)'
>>> 
>>> regex = re.compile(pattern, re.S)
>>> 
>>> result = regex.search(t).groups()[0]
>>> result
'LIB_TO_INCLUDE \n        a\n        b\n        c'
```

You can then eliminate the extra spacing and new lines:

```
>>> ' '.join(x.strip() for x in result.split('\n'))
'LIB_TO_INCLUDE a b c'
```

Note than in your link, if you switch to "python" in the "Flavors" on the left you'll get the errors that your particular format was causing.

**EDIT:** to get all (3) matches you need to use `<regex>.findall(...)` instead of `search`.

```
>>> tt = """# Library to include
... set(LIB_TO_INCLUDE 
...         a
...         b
...         c)
... 
... # comon code (inclusion in source code)
... set(SHARED_TO_INCLUDE d e f)
... 
... # Library to include
... set(THIRD_PARTY g h)"""
>>> 

>>> result = regex.findall(tt)
>>> result
['LIB_TO_INCLUDE \n        a\n        b\n        c', 'SHARED_TO_INCLUDE d e f', 'THIRD_PARTY g h']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!